# PHP why can I new an Object after `spl_autoload_unregister`?

Tags: php, autoload

My codes

`spl_autoload.php`

```php
<?php

function autoload_in_dir($class_name, $dir)
{
    echo "autoload in " . $dir . " classname: " . $class_name . "\n";

    $class_path = $dir . $class_name . '.class.php';
    if (file_exists($class_path)) {
        require_once $class_path;
    } else {
        echo 'class file' . $class_path . 'not found!';
    }
}

function autoload_in_current_dir($class_name)
{
    autoload_in_dir($class_name, "./");
} 

spl_autoload_register('autoload_in_current_dir');

$person = new Person("Yi", 28); // 1
var_dump($person); // 2

spl_autoload_unregister("autoload_in_current_dir");

$person = new Person("Yifan", 28);
var_dump($person);
```

output:

```
autoload in ./ classname: Person
object(Person)#1 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(2) "Yi"
  ["age"]=>
  int(28)
}
object(Person)#2 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "Yifan"
  ["age"]=>
  int(28)
}
```

It's ok, but I have unregistered. why can I new an Object after `spl_autoload_unregister`?

---

but if remove the following line:

```
$person = new Person("Yi", 28); // 1
var_dump($person); // 2
```

I get Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Person' not found in ...

What's the `spl_autoload_register` execution order?

---

PS:

PHP 7.1

Comment: Autoloader is responsible for loading unknown classes. When you use `Person` class first time, it will be loaded by autoloader - since this point you don't need autoloader to use this class.

Comment: @rob006 after I use Person class the first time, I did unregister the function, but I still can new the Person class

Comment: Class needs to be load only one time - after first usage you don't need autoloader anymore to use already autoloaded class.